# How to position a button in lower right of screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader, swiftui-zstack

Consider the following view:

```
var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { geo in
        
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing:  0) {
                VStack {
                    Text("The number two")
                    Text("2")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.purple)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("The number eight")
                    Text("8")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
                
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }) {
                Text("NEXT")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.orange)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  10))
            .position(x:geo.size.width, y:geo.size.height)
            .padding(16)
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.gray)
        
    }
    
}
```

On all devices, I want the button positioned in the lower right of the screen, 16 pixels from the trailing edge, and 16 pixels from the bottom edge, regardless of what else is on the screen (in the ZStack). What is the best practice to achieve that? Here's what it looks like now:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could use the safeAreaInset from the GeometryReader, no? let safeArea = geo.safeAreaInsets and from there you the safe area sizes for top, bottom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is behaving the way it is because `position` in SwiftUI positions the *center* of the `View`. But, you don't actually need `position` or `GeometryReader` to do this.

You can assign a `frame` to the orange button and align it to `bottomTrailing`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing:  0) {
                VStack {
                    Text("The number two")
                    Text("2")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.purple)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("The number eight")
                    Text("8")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }) {
                Text("NEXT")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.orange)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  10))
            .padding(16)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing) // <-- Here
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.gray)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but why doesn't `maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity` in the button frame make the button fill up all the space in ZStack? To be clear, I don't want it to, just curious what that is doing exactly.

Comment: No, it doesn't make the `Button` take up all of that space and doesn't block interaction. It adds a `frame` around the `Button` that takes up that space.

Comment: You can also achieve this with stacks and spacers, but it doesn't improve readability or functionality at all

Comment: No, it doesn't -- you can run the code and verify that. If you put the `frame` _inside_ the `Button`'s label, it would do that, but that's not what this code does.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ZStack` is already occupying the full screen by virtue of the frame with maxWidth and maxHeight. So the button can be shown as an overlay in the bottom trailing corner. If fact, if the button is shown as an overlay then you don't need the `ZStack` at all, you can promote the `HStack` to top-level instead.

However, the top-level parent (be it `ZStack` or `HStack`) is currently not ignoring the safe areas. This means, if there are insets at the bottom or side of the screen then the distance to the button will be (insets + 16). This is probably more than you want.

Assuming you don't want to ignore the safe area insets with the parent container, one way to move the button closer to the edges would be to set offsets equal to the size of the insets. The `GeometryReader` gives you these:

```swift
.offset(
    x: geo.safeAreaInsets.trailing,
    y: geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom
)
```

I would suggest, a better approach is to apply padding only where it is needed. If the insets already exceed the padding, then no more padding is needed.

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        HStack(spacing:  0) {
            // content as before
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Button("NEXT") {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.orange)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  10))
            .padding(.trailing, max(0, 16 - geo.safeAreaInsets.trailing))
            .padding(.bottom, max(0, 16 - geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
        }
        .background(.gray)
    }
}
```

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: Answer updated with a better way of handling insets