# How can I place a NavigationLink in the top right corner of a view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to place a SwiftUI `NavigationLink` in a view, and I'm having some trouble achieving both of these things:

1. Place a `NavigationLink` in the top right corner of a view.
2. Have the "tap location" for the `NavigationLink` be exactly where the label is (and active across the whole label).

This code achieves #2, but not #1:

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
  OverviewButton()
}
```

Whereas this code achieves #1, but not #2 (the tap location is slightly offset (a few pixels to the right and down) from the NavigationLink

```swift
HStack {
    Spacer()
    VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
            OverviewButton().padding(75)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

And this is the code for `OverviewButton`

```swift
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).fill(.gray.opacity(0.5))
    Label(
        title: { Text("Overview").font(.headline) },
        icon: { Image(systemName: "arrowshape.forward.circle").resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20) }
    ).labelStyle(.titleAndIcon).foregroundColor(.white)
}.frame(width: 130, height: 30)
```

How can I make a NavigationLink that accomplishes both tasks?

Comment: Regarding safe areas, the answer to this post might help: [How to position a button in lower right of screen in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77956712/20386264)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
                    OverviewButton()
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // Remove the default button style to avoid extra padding
                .padding(.trailing, 16) // Adjust the padding as needed
            }
            Spacer()//place the spacer as per your UI need
        }
    }
}

struct OverviewButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
            Label(
                title: {
                    Text("Overview")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                },
                icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.forward.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            )
        }
        .frame(width: 130, height: 30)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I implement this fix I encounter another problem. 

The `NavigationLink` is wrapped in a `ZStack`, which contains an image `Image("img1").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` that fills the whole screen. 

I don't think the image is covering up the `NavigationLink`, but I think it is pushing it out of the safe area. 

Do you know how to address this?

Comment: I didn't get what exactly is your requirement. It would be better if you can share your expected UI design for reference.

Comment: Also you can try to use `(contentMode: .fit)`